# Active directory like Identity Management with SQL and .Net Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, asp.net-identity

Active directory provides Users, Groups, and Groups having child groups etc. Is there any SQL, C# , ASP.net implementation that has similar active directory functionality?

ASP.net membership providers has Role based, and also Claim based. But I want Mainly Groups.

Guide me to good Identity management solution which can be extendable, allows User management, Group management, Claims, etc..